No 'OLE' editor registered against the type of file you were trying to open
In Spring Tool Suite 4, when I try to open a '.jsp' file, it is not showing the syntax highlight.
I tried to open the '.jsp' file as 'Open With' -> 'In-Place Editor', I get the following Error.
Cannot create the in-place editor.
Reason:
This is probably because there is no OLE editor registered against the type of file you were trying to open.
I tried to open the '.jsp' file as 'Open With' -> 'System Editor'.
I tried to open the '.jsp' file as 'Open With' -> 'Default Editor'.
In both the Editors, it is not showing the syntax highlighting for '.jsp' file.
How to enable the '.jsp' file syntax highlight in Spring Tool Suite 4 IDE?
I am not getting a '.jsp' file creation option in Spring Tool Suite 4 IDE.
How to resolve this issue?

The JSP files require to open with WTP. Don't try to open it with the system editor which you even not registered.
